# Javascript replace url segment with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this url `http://retail.domain.co.uk/view_orders/page/6/10?type=completed`

I want to replace `6` with `1`.  The url segment will be different depending on page, so i can't use a string replace.

```
var url = location.href.replace(, "1");
```

the new url should be `http://retail.domain.co.uk/view_orders/page/1/10?type=completed`

How do i solve this with regex?

Comment: there is some example in this website : https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a **captured group** to match `/page/` that is followed by 1 or more digits:

```
var str = 'http://retail.domain.co.uk/view_orders/page/6/10?type=completed';

var result = str.replace(/(\/page\/)\d+/, '$11');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iT6sR0/1)

Answer (score 1):

You may do like this,

```
string.replace(/\/\d+\//g, "/1/")
```